# pip install -U scikit-learn not working for me

Tags: python, pip, spyder

Whenever i try to `pip install -U scikit-learn`

it says:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
```

seems like pip command code is written as C:\Program Files... or something i can't seem to find any solution on the internet for it, i tried to install sklearn ( which what i used pip install for) but i can't seem to find a link for a manual installation either and i am stuck with this error.

i have spyder 3.7.9

Comment: if you are using anaconda, then install it in anaconda prompt instead of command prompt

Comment: This only occurs for scikit-learn? Or for all of pip? Or just the -U option?

Comment: Navigate to the `scripts` subfolder of your Python installation and issue the command from there. It appears that the `pip` you are running is not the one you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a virtual environment, on Ubuntu (sudo apt-get python3 - m venv venv)
The enter with (source venv/bin/activate)
The try the pip install command again.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can pip install scikit- learn
No U

Answer (score -1):

I solved it,
i installed Anaconda and from there i launched spyder 4.2.5, ran the same command and it worked